# Corrupted struct char arrays - sqlite C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am a bit puzzled by this one. Everything has been fine so far with using SQLite but now I am trying to store my query results in a simple struct. When I do this in my callback, all my data looks great in my SQLItems vector but as soon as the callback exits, my SQLItems vector holding my rows of data is suddenly corrupted. Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
// Simple struct to hold column name and row data
struct SQLrow {
    char   * Column;
    char   * Data;
};

// static Vector to hold SQL rows
static std::vector<SQLrow>       SQLItems;

...
// static callback that handles placing query results into structs and into SQLItems vector
// SQLItems column/row data gets corrupted after this function exits
static int countTablesCallback(void *data, int count, char **rows, char **azColName) {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            SQLrow newItem = { azColName[i] ,rows[i] };
            SQLItems.push_back(newItem);
        }
        *static_cast<std::vector<SQLrow>*>(data) = SQLItems; // Tried this too but throws an exception 
        return 0;
    }
```

I also thought maybe it is only possible to statically cast from the callback to save the vector but that is throwing an exception as well. Stumped here. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: If you want to access the results of a select, don't use that callback interface with `sqlite3_exec()`. Use a [prepared statement](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) in a loop. Much easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector is fine, the `static_cast` makes no sense there, unless `data` is actually used as an out parameter. Your problem is, most likely, that `SQLrow` holds char pointer and SQLite deletes the pointed-to strings after the callback returns. Changing your class to

```
struct SQLrow {
    std::string Column;
    std::string Data;
};
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the code, it appears that the data pointed to by `rows` will be invalidated/destroyed/changed once the callback returns.  So you can't retain those pointers for later use, and will have to make a copy of the data.

One easy way is to change `Column` and `Data` from `char *` to `std::string`. Failing that, you'll have to do some sort of manual memory management (allocate space with `new`, then delete it later) which is error prone and not really advisable these days.

Comment: You and @Timo are correct. Just out of curiosity, how would one go about actually using char * data types instead of std::string? Do you have have an example of this somewhere that I can wrap my head around?

Comment: Add a constructor to SQLrow that takes two td::string like: SQLrow(std::string Column, std::string Data): Column(Column), data(Data){}.

Comment: Then use it by building the two strings first like this: std::string c(azColName[i]); std::string d(rows[i]); , and then to build your SQLrow like this: SQLrow row(c, d); then push it.

Comment: @Antonio I like your suggestion but I meant how would I possibly go about doing this without using std::string types?

Comment: @drwbns If you don't want to use `std::string` and its automatic management of memory, you'll have to manually allocate space for the data.  Something like `new char[strlen(rows[i])+1]`, copy the data in, then remember to call `delete [] Data` when you're done with it.  Lots of simple ways to mess that up and, like I said in my answer, not advisable these days.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Got it! Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are very few case in which you want/need to use raw string in c++ and yours isn't one of those. By the way I hope this will help you or someone else in some way:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>


struct SQLrow {
    char* Column;
    char* Data;
};

void your_callback(int count, char **rows, char **azColName) {

    std::vector<SQLrow> rows_list;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        /* Uncomment this if you want 
           your copy of the strings. If you
           use this, don't forget to free the
           memory yourself with delete[] s1 and
           s2.

        size_t s1_len = strlen(rows[i]);
        size_t s2_len = strlen(azColName[i]);

        char* s1 = new char [sizeof(char) * (s1_len + 1)];
        char* s2 = new char [sizeof(char) * (s2_len + 1)];

        memcpy(s1, rows[i], s1_len);
        s1[s1_len] = '\0';

        memcpy(s2, azColName[i], s2_len);
        s2[s2_len] = '\0';

        SQLrow r = { s1, s2 }; */

        SQLrow r = { rows[i], azColName[i] };

        rows_list.push_back(r);
    }

    // test the result
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        SQLrow r = rows_list.at(i);

        std::cout << "rows:" << r.Column << " azColName:" << r.Data << std::endl;
    }
}

// this 2 lines are just for simulating the data
// you will get this 'warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to   char*''
char* rows[] = {"row1", "row2" , "row3" };
char* colName[] = {"name1", "name2", "name3" };

int main()
{
    your_callback(3, rows, colName);

    return 0;
}
```